# Как умножить на процент?

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика

Есть переменная а = 5000
Переменная b = 12
Как мне увеличить 5000 на 12 процентов?

Я знаю, что дабы умножить на 12% нужно 5000*0.12, но тогда другой вопрос
Как мне превратить 12 в 0.12?

Comment: 12 разделить на 100, может быть?

Comment: 5000 * (1 + 0.12),  разве нет?

Comment: Ну школьная математика же!

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что ну должен же быть какой-то минимальный порог для вопросов! Этот уже совсем рядом с "сколько будет 2*2?"

Answer (score 2):

5000 * 1.12, где увеличение на 12%, т.е 5000 превратить в 112%

Answer (score 2):

```
a+(a*(b/100)) = 5600.0
```

где, (a*(b/100)) = 12% от a = 600

или как писал выше [Johny Mc](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/328215/johnny-mc):

```
a*(1+b/100) = 5600.000000000001
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну как вариант
a*b/100 ?
Или это слишком просто?

Comment: Это слишком неправильно...